# keeping DLL on local computer secret, despite sharing with other programs on local computer

Tags: c++, security, dll, reverse-engineering

I've seen lots of discussion on this forum about keeping code secret, mainly in terms of preventing reverse engineering and decompiling.  The typical answer is something along the lines of reverse engineering is always possible, and only thing 100% secure is not distributing your code.

I wrote a c++ function and compiled into a DLL that will only be kept on my computer.  However, it needs to be used by an executable on my computer that (1) I didn't write, and (2) needs an internet connection.  Is there anything I can do to ensure that the executable doesn't "reveal" the inner-workings my function to anyone at a remove location?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your computer could be hacked, either by the one program using your DLL or by any other software you're using, and once hacked the DLL can be collected if it's of any interest to the attacker.
2. The software using your DLL may have the capability to upload the DLL, either directly or indirectly (such as by reporting crashes and logs)
3. If this DLL is manually injected into the program (or does anything else that may seem suspicious), it may be identified as a cheating/hacking tool either by part of the program or by things such as third party AVs (which occasionally love uploading files to their backend).

The three scenarios are not all that plausible, and unless this DLL contains a real secret or you have a real adversary interested in the content of your DLL i'd say you don't need to worry too much.